# Concise way to split a path so that it includes the filename and two directories up in Python?

Tags: python, filepath

What is the most concise way to split a path so that it includes the filename and two directories up in Python?

```
>>> path = r'/absolute/path/to/file.txt'
>>> os.path.dirname(path)
```

Gives:

```
/absolute/path/to
```

While:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = r'/absolute/path/to/file.txt'
>>> Path(path).parents[1]
```

gives:

```
/absolute/path
```

What would be the most concise strategy to give me:

```
to/file.txt
```

?

Comment: By 'two up' you mean all except the first two of the absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> os.path.join(*pathlib.Path(path).parts[-2:])
'to/file.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

```
path = r'/absolute/path/to/file.txt'

res = '/'.join(path.split('/')[-2:])

print(res)
# to/file.txt
```

A less concise, but better, alternative:

```
res = os.path.join(*os.path.normpath(path).split(os.sep)[-2:])
```